# Is there a way to loop through a list with this code?

Tags: python, loops, google-maps

Basically, I have a list of around 5,000 latitude and longitudes that I want to loop and run this query each individually. I have been doing this by hand and running the query's individually, but I imagine there must be a way to standardize the process. Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated, Thanks!

```
df = []

places_result = gmaps.places(query=query, location=(latitude1, longitude1), radius=32186.9, )

for place in places_result['results']:
    my_place_id = place['place_id']

    my_fields = ['name', 'business_status', 'formatted_address', 'opening_hours', 'rating', 'website',
                 'formatted_phone_number', 'geometry/location/lng', 'geometry/location/lat']

    place_details = gmaps.place(place_id=my_place_id, fields=my_fields)

    column_names = ['name', 'rating', 'address', 'website', 'phone', 'status', 'hours', 'lat', 'lng']

    # df=pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

    try:
        rating = place_details['result']['rating']
    except KeyError:
        rating = 'na'
    try:
        name = place_details['result']['name']
    except KeyError:
        name = "na"
    try:
        address = place_details['result']['formatted_address']
    except KeyError:
        address = "na"
    try:
        website = place_details['result']['website']
    except KeyError:
        website = "na"
    try:
        phone = place_details['result']['formatted_phone_number']
    except KeyError:
        phone = "na"
    try:
        lat = place_details['result']['geometry']['location']['lat']
    except KeyError:
        lat = "na"
    try:
        lng = place_details['result']['geometry']['location']['lng']
    except KeyError:
        lng = "na"
    try:
        status = place_details['result']['business_status']
    except KeyError:
        status = "na"
    try:
        hours = place_details['result']['opening_hours']
    except KeyError:
        hours = 'na'

    df1 = {"name": [name, ], "rating": [rating, ], "address": [address, ], "website": [website, ], "phone": [phone, ],
           "status": [status, ], "hours": [hours, ], "lat": [lat, ], "lng": [lng, ]}
    data: DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)
    df.append(data)
dfr = pd.concat(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
places_result = gmaps.places(query=query, location=(latitude1, longitude1), radius=32186.9)

def get_field_value(result, field):
  try:
    for f in field.split('/'):
      result = result[f]
    return result
  except KeyError:
    return 'na'

col_field = [ ('name', 'name'),
              ('rating', 'rating')
              ('address', 'formatted_address')
              ('website', 'website')
              ('phone', 'formatted_phone_number')
              ('status', 'business_status')
              ('hours', 'opening_hours')
              ('lat', 'geometry/location/lat')
              ('lng', 'geometry/location/lng')
            ]
fields = [e[1] for e in col_field]

for place in places_result['results']:
    place_details_result = gmaps.place(place_id=place['place_id'], fields=fields)['result']
    df1 = { column: [get_field_value(place_details_result, field)] for column, field in col_field }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, regarding your try, except blocks, you can rewrite those with:

```
result = place_details['result']

rating = result.get('rating', 'na')
name = result.get('name', 'na')
...
```

and so on.
The dict.get(key, default=None) method will avoid raising a KeyError and you can provide a default value, 'na' in your case.

You can further slim that down with a dictionary comprhension:

```
keys = ["name", "rating", "address", "website", "phone",
        "status", "hours", "lat", "lng"]
entry = {k: result.get(k, 'na') for k in keys}
```

Assuming you have your lat and lon values in two lists:

```
entries = []
for lat, lon in zip(latitudes, longitudes):
    q = gmaps.places(query=query, location=(lat, lon), radius=32186.9,)
    result = q.get('result', {})  # returns an empty dict if the query fails
    entry = {k: result.get(k, 'na') for k in keys}
    entries.append(entry)

df = pd.DataFrame(entries)  # create a pandas dataframe
```